# Having trouble creating script to find the name that shows up in each list in Python

Tags: python

Dr. Smith was killed in the studio with a knife by one of his heirs! Create a script to find the murderer! Make sure to show your answer.

The following people are Smith's heirs: Aiden, Tori, Lucas, Isabelle.
The following people were in the studio: Lucas, Natalie, Tori.
The following people own a knife: Isabelle, Tori, Natalie.

My code:

```
heirs = ["Aiden", "Tori", "Lucas", "Isabelle"]
ppleinstudio = ["Lucas", "Natalie", "Tori"]
knife = ["Isabelle", "Tori", "Natalie"]

# killer is the one who exists in three of the lists
# merge the lists

merged = [*heirs,*ppleinstudio,*knife]

L1=[]
for i in merged:
    if i not in L1:
        L1.append(i)
    else:
        print(i,end=' ')
```

output:
Lucas Tori Isabelle Tori Natalie

What am I missing to get it to look for the repeating name?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, cycle through each entry in the merged list, and break the three requirements into three boolean statements:

```
heirs = ["Aiden", "Tori", "Lucas", "Isabelle"]
ppleinstudio = ["Lucas", "Natalie", "Tori"]
knife = ["Isabelle", "Tori", "Natalie"]

# killer is the one who exists in three of the lists
# merge the lists

merged = [*heirs,*ppleinstudio,*knife]

for person in merged:
    is_heir = person in heirs
    is_in_studio = person in ppleinstudio
    has_knife = person in knife
    if(is_heir and is_in_studio and has_knife):
        print(person)
        break
```

Output:

```
Tori
```

This will be a little inefficient because if you print out the contents of merged, you'll notice that there are duplicate names, but seeing as your question doesn't mention anything about efficiency - this will get the job done just fine.

If you are concerned about this inefficiency you can use the `set` operator on the `merged` list and iterate over that instead:

```
merged = set(merged)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that the code you implemented is doing what you wanted it to do, maybe you should try to check the contents of the merged list and see what happens as you iterate through the for loop.

Nevertheless, for the sake of providing a solution to your problem, if you are allowed to use sets you could easily solve this by doing the following:

```
heirs = ["Aiden", "Tori", "Lucas", "Isabelle"]
ppleinstudio = ["Lucas", "Natalie", "Tori"]
knife = ["Isabelle", "Tori", "Natalie"]

h_set = set(heirs)
s_set = set(ppleinstudio)
k_set = set(knife)

culprit = h_set.intersection(s_set.intersection(k_set)).pop()
print(culprit)
>> 'Tori'
```

But if this is some kind of homework you should probably try to work your way to a solution on paper/whiteboard first, and figure out why your approach is not working.